# How to iterate through multiple rows in jquery using ajax, json, and php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a php page that returns json like this:

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

When I run the php page I get back something like:

```
[{"phone":"1234567"},{"phone":"1234567"}]
```

This is my jquery code:

```
   $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(response) {

             $.each(response, function() { 
                $.each(this, function(key, value){
                    alert(key + " --> " + value); 
                });
            });

        }
   });

});
```

I got that from another SO question.  This will give me my keys and value in the alert.  This was just for me to make sure everything works.  I have searched but cannot figure out how to just get one value.  Say I wanted the name, what do I put?  I have tried:

```
success: function(response) {
 var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
 alert( obj.phone );
}
```

But since it is multiple rows it won't work unless I have, and it also fails when I have one row like this:

```
echo json_encode(array("phone" => "123")
```

How do I get a single value from a row?
How do I iterate through multiple rows and only get one of the column values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `response` variable is an array of objects. To access a single index in your `response` variable:

```
var phone = response[0].phone;//replace `0` with the index you want
```

If you end-up iterating through your response in a loop make sure to do it like this for the best performance:

```
var len = response.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    console.log(response[i].phone);
}
```

Check-out this jsperf to see how much faster this type of loop is than `for(i in array)`: http://jsperf.com/for-in-tests

Comment: this works for multiple rows but why won't it work for this:  echo json_encode(array("phone" => "1234"));  Thank you btw (everyone).

Comment: @johnny Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5bRbe/. I used `echo json_encode(array("phone" => "1234"));` to get the JSON for the demo.

Answer (score 2):

The response JSON is an array. To get the first phone number, retrieve the first object through `response[0]`, then get the property using `.phone`:

```
    success: function(response) {  //response = array, when using dataType:"JSON"
         alert(response[0].phone);
    }
```

Replace 0 with any number between 0 and `response.length` to get the corresponding phone property.

Comment: The code in your question is not representing the actual situation. Does your response **really** look like `[{"phone":"..."}, ...]` ?

Comment: Is this php wrong?  echo json_encode(array("phone" => "1234"));  It returns {"phone":"1234"} when I run the php page.

Comment: To create a test case which reflects your described environment, use: `<?php echo json_encode(array(array("phone" => "1234")));?>`, which results in `[{"phone":"1234"}]`. **If you want to use `{"phone":"1234"}`, use `response.phone`** instead of `response[0].phone`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
for (var i; i < response.length; i++) {
    console.log(response[i].phone);
}
```

Comment: that did not work sorry.  It never displays anything.  thanks.

Comment: i know, sorry, it was mistake, i have fixed it.

Comment: This is how I used to do loops until I tested the different ways. Check-out this JavaScript Performance test: http://jsperf.com/for-in-tests